# Implications of ヒロイン (Heroine) in stories

Tags: culture

I've read that ヒロイン , meaning 'heroine', can also imply a romantic interest to the hero pretty much by default culturally in Japan's stories.

I can't seem to find any definitive source for this from a native speaker, though, so I'm wondering if anyone on the language speaking boards has heard this before?

Comment: `"pretty much by default culturally"` は言い過ぎちゃうかな・・みたいな？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a love story like *Romeo and Juliet*, yes, ヒロイン refers to a main female character who will (eventually) fall in love with a main male character.

In other types of stories, ヒロイン can simply refer to the most significant female character in a story, and you can use ヒロイン when there is no romance concerned at all. A ヒロイン tends to be young and beautiful, but can be an old lady, too. For example Joan of Arc, [Yotsuba Koiwai](http://azumanga.wikia.com/wiki/Yotsuba_Koiwai), [Pretty Cures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Cure) and [Maiden in Black](http://demonssouls.wikia.com/wiki/Maiden_in_Black) can be called ヒロイン. Still, 主人公 may be a safer term when there is no romance concerned.

Answer (score 2):

ヒロイン has a few definitions. In most cases, it means the female protagonist in a story. It can also mean a heroic female character. Another meaning would be the female partner of the main character. ヒロイン can also take on the meaning of a 'love interest'.

See this [Wikipedia entry](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%92%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3).